# How can the basis for $V$ be determined?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $T \in L(V)$. Let $B$ be a basis for $V$ such that $[T]_B = A$. Let $A$ be similar to a matrix $D$. Then does there exist any basis $B'$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{B'} = D$?

If the answer is 'yes' how can the basis $B'$ for $V$ be determined? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If $A=XDX^{-1}$, then $X$ converts between coordinates with respect to $B$ and $B'$.

Comment: Would you please explain the line ''$X$ converts between coordinates...''? Then it will be helpful to me to understand what your reasoning exactly is.